# C: Help finding memory faults

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

My program is written in C and it is a disk emulator. I finished writing it and it runs when I comment out certain lines of my test program, but I get a memory error where I un-comment them. I suspect it is with my char* 's.

The line I comment out (and where the program crashes) is

```
free(buffer);
```

where buffer is the char* that the string of bytes that was read into from the disk. It was initially allocated 30 bytes using malloc.

```
char* buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
```

There is too much to just post it all here, so I am going to put the parts where I am writing/copying to char* 's in the hopes that someone will see what I am doing wrong.

I don't think it is anything too complicated, I am just not familiar enough with C the recognize obvious memory mistakes.

```
 // In the event of a cache miss:

 // block_buffer to pass to add_cache_entry
 char cMissBuffer[BLOCK_SIZE];

 // read content of block from disk 
 fread(cMissBuffer,sizeof(char),BLOCK_SIZE,diskEntity.pBlockStore);

 // add to cache
 if(1==add_cache_entry(i,cMissBuffer)) return 1;
 .
 .
 .
 // some of what is in add_cache_entry

 int add_cache_entry(int v, char *block_buffer)
 {
    // ...
    // construct a new queue element
    QueueElement *block_to_cache = (QueueElement*)malloc(sizeof(QueueElement));
    block_to_cache->blkidx = v;

    block_to_cache->content=(char*)malloc(BLOCK_SIZE);
    strcpy(block_to_cache->content,block_buffer);
// ...
 }
```

In the test, BLOCK_SIZE is 5, QueueElement is a struct, content is a char* with BLOCK_BYTES of info.

Here is an excerpt from running the executable (dumping the queue)...I think that the lack of a '\0' could have something to do with the issue...

```
after adding cache entry (5):
DUMP:
BLOCK 5 FLAG:0 CONTENT:222220000000
BLOCK 4 FLAG:0 CONTENT:222220000000
BLOCK 3 FLAG:0 CONTENT:000000000000
BLOCK 2 FLAG:0 CONTENT:000000000000
BLOCK 1 FLAG:1 CONTENT:11100
```

I think I get extra space because malloc allocates more space than I require, but I read that is normal.

Any thoughts?

Comment: *"it functions correctly when I comment out certain lines of my test program, so the functionality is correct"* - 1. That is evidence that your program is functionally *incorrect*. 2 - Your code may run without crashing and still be incorrect (i.e., undefined behavior).  3. It would be best to practice reasoning about the behavior of your code instead of randomly changing things until it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A probable cause for the behaviour is that `strcpy()` requires the source string to be null terminated, which is not the case here as `fread()` does not append a null terminator for you (nor could it in this case as `fread()` is reading the exact buffer size). `strcpy()` also appends a null terminator which means the `strcpy()` call will definitely be writing beyond the `block_to_cache->content` buffer.

If the data is not be used as a C style string use `memcpy()` to copy the data instead:

```
memcpy(block_to_cache->content, block_buffer, BLOCK_SIZE);
```

---

Other points:

- Check the return value of [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread), to ensure it successfully populated the buffer before attempting to use it.
- it is unnecessary to cast the return value of `malloc()` (see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)).
- check return value of `malloc()` to ensure memory was successful allocated.
- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be one so can be removed from argument to `malloc()`.

Comment: valgrind is very helpful to find memory errors - have You tried to run Your application under it ?